# GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime and QueryPerformanceCounter

Tags: c++, windows, time

I'm wondering if the windows function `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` use the `QueryPerformanceCounter` / RDTSC counter to retrieve UTC time at the sub-microseconds resolution ?

Comment: There is a very heavy inference but no outright guarantee.  Quote: "The TSC synchronization algorithm was significantly improved to better accommodate large systems with many processors. In addition, support for the new precise time-of-day API was added, which enables acquiring precise wall clock time stamps from the operating system. For more info, see GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime."

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed, it seems to be the case so.

Answer (score 2):

Internally `GetSystemTimeAsPreciseFileTime` does use `QueryPerformanceCounter`, some values from [`USER_SHARED_DATA`](https://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/WRK/2007/08/getting-os-information-the-kuser_shared_data-structure/), and some arithmetic to return its value.